# Display pre-typed Outlook mail in new install of Office 2016

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, excel-2016

I have a few VBA macros that don't work since I installed the 2016 version of Office.

It's the bit to display a pre-typed email that doesn't work. The rest of the code runs as it should.

```
Sub Send_Application()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("NumberOfApps").Cells
        If cell.Value = "Y" Then
            cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = Worksheets("Data").Range("A2")
            cell.Value = "SENT"
            cell.Offset(0, 18).Value = "Yes"

            Dim OutApp As Object
            Dim OutMail As Object
            Dim strbody As String
            Dim sTo As String

            AppName = "J:\Matrixes\All Sites\Applications\" & Worksheets("Data").Range("E3") & "\" & cell.Offset(0, 13).Value & ".pdf"

            Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            strbody = Worksheets("Data").Range("G2") & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Please find attached our application for payment for the month of " & Worksheets("Data").Range("E2") & "." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Can I ask you to check you are happy with this application and I will issue an Vat Invoice to you. If you do have any queries can you please notify me by email before the 15th " & _ 
              Worksheets("Data").Range("E4") & " otherwise we look forward receiving your payment " & Worksheets("Data").Range("E6") & "." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Thank You" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Kind Regards"

            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = sTo
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = cell.Offset(0, 13).Value
                .Body = strbody
                .Attachments.Add (AppName)
                'You can add a file like this
                '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
                .Display   'or use .Display
            End With
            'On Error GoTo 0

            Set OutMail = Nothing
            Set OutApp = Nothing

        End If

    Next cell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I have commented out the "On Error Resume" lines but there are no errors that appear.

I have run Excel and Outlook as administrator, enabled all macros temporarily in both.

If I write a brand new macro using the same text, it works until I close Excel. Then I need to do it again.

I searched for a solution but everything I tried hasn't worked.

Comment: You commented out the wrong  "On Error Resume" lines, Should be `On Error Resume Next` also your missing underscore on `\Applications\" &` should be `\Applications\" & _`

Comment: Can you share example of spreadsheet? Or post image?

Answer (score 1):

With you code do the following:

- Select the `Sub Send_Application()` with your mouse
- Press <kbd>F8</kbd>
- Press <kbd>F8</kbd>
- Press <kbd>F8</kbd>

and so on. You should be getting every line in yellow like this:

[image]

Does it work?

Comment: Many thanks. It gets down to the line before "Dim OutApp As Object" and then it skips to "End If" right at the bottom. It skips all the lines regarding the email creation.

Comment: @LeeKitson - can you write `Option Explicit` on the top of the module, debug your code and fix it everywhere? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/option-explicit-statement

Comment: I'm fairly new to VBA and that seems far too advanced for me. I'm modifying an ex colleagues code. Everything ran perfectly until we upgraded to Office 2016. People who are still on Office 2010 have no problems.

Comment: @LeeKitson Code will not work on 2010, you have lots errors

Comment: @0m3r - Any ideas whatthose errors are? The code works perfectly on my computer running 2010. Those that are running 2016 are having trouble.